# Download file from internet and serve to website using Django without exposing URL

Tags: python, django

I am downloading an audio file using some URL get request. I cannot expose the URL, as it contains an API-key. What is the right way to serve this file to a website?

Comment: will you please elaborate what exactly do you mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a view where you download the file and then serve back the file in a response to your frontend.

[Here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/outputting-csv/#streaming-large-csv-files) is the Django docs showing you how to stream a file as a response using a generator.

```
import requests
from django.http import StreamingHttpResponse


def stream_audio(request):
    file_url = "your.url.com"
    r = requests.get(file_url, stream=True)
    response = StreamingHttpResponse(streaming_content=r, content_type='audio/mpeg')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="somefilename.mp3"'
    return response
```

This way you never expose your API key but you can send the same information to the user.